# Can't open file 'file.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python

I'm using Windows10 and wants to run my python script by cmd

The command:

`python file.py`

return the message:

`python: can't open file 'file.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

but when I run 
 `python C:\Python37\projects\file.py`
it's run properly

**also, I added  `C:\Python37\projects` to the PATH, but it doesn't help**

Comment: By this `PATH` system variable, did you mean this - https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm#windows10 ? Or do you mean some other method to add to the system variable `PATH` ? Are you trying to use your "command" directly from the Windows console ? Or are you trying it via the `.bat` / `.cmd` script ? Or are you trying it possibly via the `.vbs` (VisualBasic) script ?

Answer (score 1):

When you run a script from the prompt you need to use the whole path to the file (as you did when running python C:\Python37\projects\file.py) or you need to first move to the directory containing the file and then run, otherwise you rise the error you got (cause there's no file with such name in your current directory). You can move to another directory using the command cd. So what you could do if you don't want to type the path every time you run the code is:

```
cd C:\Python37\projects
python file.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set an environment variable PYTHONPATH to a directory where you put your scripts. Then you can run your script just as

```
python script.py
```

Comment: I tested this and it does not work for running the code as a script - only for running the code as a module using the `-m` flag. Since `PYTHONPATH` specifies additional directories to add **to `sys.path`, to look for things to `import`**, the result is not surprising.

Answer (score 0):

Open your script in another code editor like VS and check extension. It usually keeps txt behind py and that is why you get an error. Or in Options, if you use Windows, Hide extensions for known file types.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the environment you have done your installation. Then call the path of your  directory rightly.

> cd C:\Python37\projects

> python file.py